# if statement in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

this is my statement

```
=IF(G7 < 6, G7 * D22) + IF(5 < G7 < 11, G7 * D23) + IF(10 < G7, G7 * D24)
```

it works if G7 cell value is less then 6 or greater then 10, but if G7 value is from 6 to 10 the result is 0.
Cell D23 has value of 15.

What can be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess, but you might want to edit the middle statement to this;

```
IF(AND( G7 < 5, G7 < 11), G7 * D23)
```

Comment: Perhaps `=IF(G7 < 6, G7 * D22) + IF(AND( G7 >= 6, G7 < 11), G7 * D23) + IF(G7>=11, G7 * D24)`

Answer (score 0):

In the "Formulas" tab, "Formula Auditing" section you will find an "Evaluate Formula" button.  This will show you the issue.

In the IF(5 < G7 < 11, G7 * D23) statement, when G7=6, the "5 < *6*" portion evaluates to "TRUE".  Next, this is evaluated as "*TRUE* < 11", which returns FALSE.  This can be fixed by evaluating the comparisons to 5 and 11 separately.

```
 IF(AND(5 < G12,G12 < 11), G12 * $D$23)
```

Personally, I would explicitly state the [value if false], but that's not strictly necessary.

```
=IF(G7 < 6, G7 * D22,0) + IF(AND(5 < G7,G7 < 11), G7 * D23,0) + IF(10 < G7, G7 * D24,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

`=IF(G7<6,D22,IF(G7<11,D23,D24))*G7`

You don't need an AND when you have nested IFs because the first IF has already dealt with <6 values so when the second IF is processed you only need the upper bound, similarly there is no 3rd IF because after the first two IFs all remaining values must fall in category 3

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Pankaj Jaju gave correct answer.

=IF(G7 < 6, G7 * D22) + IF(AND( G7 >= 6, G7 < 11), G7 * D23) + IF(G7>=11, G7 * D24)

I tried it (actually I put AND(G7 > 5 instead of G7 >= 6), but it is the same) and it works.

Thank you